# Calculating Hessian with tensorflow gradient tape

Tags: tensorflow, autodiff

Thank you for your interest in this issue.

I want to calculate hessian matrix of tensorflow.keras.Model

for high order derivates, i tried nested GradientTape.# example graph, and inputs

```
xs = tf.constant(tf.random.normal([100,24]))

ex_model = Sequential()
ex_model.add(Input(shape=(24)))
ex_model.add(Dense(10))
ex_model.add(Dense(1))

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    tape.watch(xs)
    ys = ex_model(xs)
g = tape.gradient(ys, xs)
h = tape.jacobian(g, xs)
print(g.shape)
print(h.shape)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-dbf443f1ddab> in <module>
      5 h = tape.jacobian(g, xs)
      6 print(g.shape)
----> 7 print(h.shape)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

And, another trial...

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape1:
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape2:
        tape2.watch(xs)
        ys = ex_model(xs)
    g = tape2.gradient(ys, xs)
h = tape1.jacobian(g, xs)
    
print(g.shape)
print(h.shape)


(100, 24)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-c5bbb17404bc> in <module>
      7 
      8 print(g.shape)
----> 9 print(h.shape)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

why i cannot calculate gradient of g wrt x ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already calculate the `ys` second order of gradients wrt `xs` which is zero, as it should be when you calculate gradients wrt constant, and that is why `tape1.jacobian(g, xs)` return `None`

When second order of gradients **not** wrt constant:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense

x = tf.Variable(1.0)
w = tf.constant(3.0)
with tf.GradientTape() as t2:
  with tf.GradientTape() as t1:
    y = w * x**3
  dy_dx = t1.gradient(y, x)
d2y_dx2 = t2.gradient(dy_dx, x)

print('dy_dx:', dy_dx) # 3 * 3 * x**2 => 9.0
print('d2y_dx2:', d2y_dx2) # 9 * 2 * x => 18.0
```

Outputs:

```
dy_dx: tf.Tensor(9.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
d2y_dx2: tf.Tensor(18.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

When second order of gradients **is** wrt constant:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense

x = tf.Variable(1.0)
w = tf.constant(3.0)
with tf.GradientTape() as t2:
  with tf.GradientTape() as t1:
    y = w * x
  dy_dx = t1.gradient(y, x)
d2y_dx2 = t2.gradient(dy_dx, x)

print('dy_dx:', dy_dx)
print('d2y_dx2:', d2y_dx2)
```

Outputs:

```
dy_dx: tf.Tensor(3.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
d2y_dx2: None
```

You could however calculate the layer parameters second order of gradients wrt `xs` like e.g [Input gradient regularization](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/advanced_autodiff#example_input_gradient_regularization)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. After I added a lambda layer with x**2 into model, nested tape return tensor. Thank you

Comment: @MyPrunus Glad to help, if my answer solved your problem then please mark it as answer so other people who with similar problem will know where to find the answer, have a good day : )